# Dynamically adding pages in a Multipage control

Tags: vba, excel

I want do add some pages in a multipage when a Initialize the form. I did it with this code:

```
Me.Controls("main").Pages.Remove (Page1)
Me.Controls("main").Pages.Remove (Page1)
For Each pagini In ws1.Range("pagini")
    Me.Controls("main").Pages.Add (pagini)
    i=i+1
Next pagini
```

In the pagini range are the names of the captions for the pages. It works fine... it generates the pages with those names but now I want to dynamically add some other controls on everypage and I have a problem... I don't know the names of the pages.
I tried to add the names in the code above but I get an error when I tried to compile

```
Me.Controls("main").Pages.Add ("test" &i,pagini)
```

So I want to add a name for every page added in that code but I don't know how.... after I add the name I want to add some other controls on each page but that's a different story and I hope I'll manage to do that!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the page count information, via `Me.Controls("main").Pages.Count` which is current after you've added the `pagini`.

Therefore, go to `Me.Controls("main").Pages(Me.Controls("main").Pages.Count)` and change whichever property you would like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So after I add pagini I should add something like Me.Controls("main").Pages(Me.Controls("main").Pages.Count).Name = "test"&i ?

Comment: @Andrei Yes that should work.  I didn't test out your example.